# Android MVVM Cross v3 - How to Create a ListView with alternating row colours

Tags: android, mvvm, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'd like to create a ListView that has an alternating background colour for each row.

I'm new to Android development in general, never mind Xamarin and MVVMCross as well :)

There are some examples of doing this in the Android world and the Xamarin world, but I can't figure out how to set this up in an MVVM Cross way.

My understanding is that I will need to implement this in the Android specific view code and to do that I will need to set some adapter on the ListView that can programatically set the background colour of each List item as they are rendered.

I found this example:

https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/Working%20With%20Collections/Collections.Droid

However, once implemented I find that none of the following methods are called on my `CustomAdapter : MvxAdapter` when displaying the view:

`GetBindableView, GetSimpleView, GetBindableView, GetView`

I also found this unanswered question

[Issue with custom listview using mono droid and mvvmcross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546487/issue-with-custom-listview-using-mono-droid-and-mvvmcross)

Which uses `MvxBindableListAdapter` which seems no longer to exist.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Here are the various code snippets involved:

TradeBookingResponseView.axml owns this:

```
<Mvx.MvxListView
  android:id="@+id/TradeConfirmation"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  local:MvxBind="ItemsSource OpenTradeListItems"
  local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_confirmation"
/>
```

inside its `LinearLayout`

item_confirmation.axml is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tradingStateIcon"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <TextView
      android:layout_weight="0.35"
      android:text="Field"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
      android:layout_width="0dip"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
      android:id="@+id/tradeConfirmationField"
      local:MvxBind="Text Field" />
    <TextView
      android:layout_weight="0.65"
      android:text="Value"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
      android:layout_width="0dip"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/tradeConfirmationValue"
      local:MvxBind="Text Value"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The TradeBookingResponseViewModel exposes this

```
public ObservableCollection<ConfirmationItem> OpenTradeListItems
{
    get
    {
        return openTradeListItems;
    }
    set
    {
        if (!Equals(value, openTradeListItems))
        {
            openTradeListItems = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => OpenTradeListItems);
        }
    }
}
```

While the view code is

```
public class TradeBookingResponseView : ViewBase
{
    public TradeBookingResponseView() : base(Resource.Layout.TradeBookingResponseView)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnViewModelSet()
    {
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.TradeBookingResponseView);
        var list = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.TradeConfirmation);
        list.Adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, (IMvxAndroidBindingContext) BindingContext);
    }
}

public class CustomAdapter : MvxAdapter
{
    public CustomAdapter(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, IMvxAndroidBindingContext bindingContext) : base(context, bindingContext)
    {
    }

    protected override View GetBindableView(View convertView, object dataContext)
    {
        convertView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Red);
        return base.GetBindableView(convertView, dataContext);
    }
}
```

Where `ViewBase` extends `MvxActivity`

And I'm setting red just to see if it gets called (it doesn't). According to more Android-y examples I want to use `View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` to see what position the item is at, so I can do % 2 on it (this also is not called).

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the color after the base method - eg

```
public override GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
      var v = base.GetView(position, convertView, parent);
      v.SetBackgroundColor( I %2 == 0 ? Color.Red : Color.Blue);
      return v;
}
```

Alternatively you could data-bind the background color if you wanted to

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to data-bind using background, in your custom table template (item_confirmation), replace my RowItem.RowId with the id of your OpenTradeListItems list:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    ...
    local:MvxBind="BackgroundColor BackgroundColor(RowItem.RowId)">
```

And here is the BackgroundColor converter:

```
public class BackgroundColorValueConverter : MvxColorValueConverter
{
    protected override MvxColor Convert(object value, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (int)value % 2 != 0 ? BusinessConstants.ThirdAlternateBGColor : null;
    }
}
```