# Mvvmcross ListView with colored rows

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, mvvmcross

Yep, it's an duplication of [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947518/android-mvvm-cross-v3-how-to-create-a-listview-with-alternating-row-colours) but, actualy, the Suart's issue doesn't work

```
public override GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
      var v = base.GetView(position, convertView, parent);
      v.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Red);
      return v;
}
```

This code does nothing - color is setted, but after return it doesn't change.

I believe I can use difrent templates for every row, but I have numerouse types of them.

So, is there any decision for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you set row colors using binding.  Install this [plugin](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-plugins#color) and then bind backgroundColor on the axml like [this](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Value-Converters#the-mvx-color-valueconverters).

Example code of axml if you use the already created value converter NativeColor which converts that color to the platform specific color:

```
local:MvxBind="BackgroundColor NativeColor(CurrentColor)"
```

In your view model for example you could then have a property:

```
public MvxColor CurrentColor { get; set; }
```

Or wherever this color needs to be stored.